# How to get a recursive selection in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm retrieving this selection from database into a datable in c#.
[image]

```
DataTable cataloguess = catalogue.CatalogueChirMedTech(id);
```

i have Categorie object, I can have under Categorie other Categorie objects(List) and under it. I can have also other Categories objects and etc(recursive).
So in c#, I want to create each Categorie with its list of categories if exists, and its modeles.Modele are rows with estterminal='o'.
Rows with pereid=-256 are parent and their children are rows with pereid is the id of the parent (typeid).

```
public class Categorie {

    private List<Categorie> sousCategoriesField;
     private List<Modele> modelesField;


    public List<Categorie> Categories {
        get {
            return this.sousCategoriesField;
        }
        set {
            this.sousCategoriesField = value;
        }
    }


public List<typeModele> modeles {
        get {
            return this.modelesField;
        }
        set {
            this.modelesField = value;
        }
    }




}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since you have a database, why are you trying to pull all the rows into your app to do processing in linq? Why not use sql to pull the data you need as needed?

Comment: This is a bit broad, have you gotten started at all?  If you write a method which takes a "parent object" and a "data source" and populates the children of that parent object, then loops over those children and recursively calls itself, then you have your recursive structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First* I suspect your `Categorie` object is going to need an identifier of some kind.  Something as simple as:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

---

The *recursive* part should be simple enough.  Logically a method might look something like this:

```
private List<Categorie> GetCategories(int ID, DataTable sourceData)
{
    var result = GetCategoriesFromData(ID, sourceData);
    foreach (var categorie in result)
        categorie.Categories = GetCategories(categorie.ID, sourceData);
    return result;
}
```

You'd need to expand on the placeholder `GetCategoriesFromData` in here, of course.  That's really up to you and outside the scope of the recursion itself.  Basically you'd query the `DataTable` for rows which have the given ID as their parent, convert those rows to `Categorie` objects (populate the `ID` and the `modeles`, whatever those are), and return that list.

But once you have this structure, the recursion is simple.  All you need to do is call it with your initial "magic number" for the top-level parent "categories":

```
DataTable cataloguess = catalogue.CatalogueChirMedTech(id);
var categories = GetCategories(-256, cataloguess);
```

Then the `GetCategories` method will recursively populate the child categories, passing along the `ID` of each "parent" at each level of recursion.

Comment: Hello David,i feel the need of a recursive method ,but i didn't undrestand what GetCategoriesFromData method will perform.

Comment: @HamzaElgarni: That's a semantic placeholder in the code shown here, just to abstract an operation unrelated to the actual recursion.  It doesn't need to be a separate method, you can perform that logic right there if you like.  The purpose of that placeholder is simply to say that, at that point in the logic, you would need to query your `DataTable` based on the given `ID` (`pereid` in the data) and convert the results to your `Categorie` object type.